# Unexpected behavior of static variables in python

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, static-members

I am learning django, here is the model i have created

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Name")
    login = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name="Login")
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Password")
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name="Phone number")

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.name
```

Since `name` is a static variable, so in method `__str__`, it can also be called like this

```
    def __str__ (self):
        return UserProfile.name
```

But when i tried to access variable using the above method , i get the following error

```
AttributeError at /admin/TasksManager/userprofile/
type object 'UserProfile' has no attribute 'name'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/TasksManager/userprofile/
Django Version: 1.6
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
type object 'UserProfile' has no attribute 'name'
Exception Location: C:\Users\X\django_book\Work_manager\TasksManager\models.py in __str__, line 18
Python Executable:  C:\Users\X\django_book\Scripts\python.EXE
Python Version: 3.4.3
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\X\\django_book\\Work_manager',
 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python34.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\X\\django_book\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\X\\django_book\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\X\\django_book\\Scripts',
 'C:\\Python34\\Lib',
 'C:\\Python34\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\X\\django_book',
 'C:\\Users\\X\\django_book\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 7 Jan 2016 23:10:34 +0530
```

Why so ??

I applied the same technique in the following class, where it works perfectly fine

```
class Rect:

    status = "this is test"

    def __init__(self, l, b):
        self.l = l
        self.b = b

    def something(self):
        return Rect.status
```

Why there is a contradiction ?

Answer (score 0):

The Django model does not contain static variables. They are used by the metaclass to define actual instance variables. You can't access them through the class.

Comment: So how can i acheive the same thing in class Rect ?

Comment: There is a lot of metaclass trickery that goes on to make this possible in Django; it's not something you can just enable.

Comment: @Cody by  [writing your own models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/_modules/django/db/models/base/#Model)

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: Just for learning purpose nothing else